# Javascript: Delete text after cursor

Tags: javascript, text

Have been trying to adapt a snippet of code I found that deletes 1 character forward in a block of text into a code snippet that deletes all text forward (i.e through the end) of the text block. I can make the length into a larger number (say 100) to capture most instances, but that does not seem as clean.

```
var sel = getSelectedRange();
var start = sel[0];
var length = sel[1];
setTextInRange(start, length == 0 ? 1 : length, "");
setSelectedRange(start, 0);
```

For example, if the text read "This is the sample text" and the cursor was in front of the word "is", the result would just be the word "This "

I am using this code in the Drafts app on iOS to process text - very new to this and first post, so hopefully I included all information...

Edit: The location of the [Drafts app help page](https://agiletortoise.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202465564-Script-Keys) that details the functions being used.

Comment: Search for the user Tim Down on this site. He has great texr range scripts.

Comment: Found Tim's answers and plenty to dig through - thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used, nor completely sure what Drafts is but having a look at the function definitions you might just need to use a different one.

```
test = "The lazy brown dog" \\ (imagine brown was selected)

sel = getSelectedRange() \\ returns [10, 5] if i counted right...
```

if you want to delete "brown dog" you can't use the length returned by `getSelectedRange` you will need to determine the length of the entire string first.

```
length = getText().length

length = length - sel[1] \\ find the length you want

setTextInRange(sel[0], length, "")
```

hope this helps

Comment: This worked absolutely perfectly - I ended up using the code exactly as suggested and it works exactly as I hoped. This makes sense and I get the logic - thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understood you but I've thrown a quick prototype together.

http://jsfiddle.net/5bLxjja9/

```
$("#Javascript_example").click(function(){

   var x = $("#Javascript_example").val();

    var newStr = []
    for(var i = 0; i< curPosition();i++){
        newStr.push(x[i]);
    }
    console.log(newStr.join(''));

    $("#Javascript_example").val(newStr.join(''));

});



function curPosition()
{
    var ctl = document.getElementById('Javascript_example');
    var curPos = ctl.selectionStart;
   return curPos;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help - but have been unable to get this to work (my issue / lack of knowledge) - using a script inside a program on an existing text block and wasn't able to translate this to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you include the code for the functions `getSelectedRange`, `setTextInRange` & `setSelectedRange`? That would give me a better idea of what `sel` is.

You're right that setting length to 100 isn't that clean. What you want to do is dynamically get the length of the rest of the text & delete that. It could be that you just want to pass in `sel.length`, but I'm not too sure what `sel` is an array of.

Comment: Added a link in the original question that has links to the functions being used - NickSlash's answer above works smooth and dynamically gets the length needed.